# Can I get an enters-the-battlefield effect out of a second legendary before I must sacrifice it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-enters-the-battlefield

If I have a legendary creature out, and I make a copy of it (such as by enchanting it with [Splinter Twin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Splinter%20Twin) or making a [Clone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clone)), do I get enters-the-battlefield effects from the creature before I have to sacrifice it to the legend rule?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

As discussed [in an article discussing the recent Legendary rules change](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/legendary-rule-change-2013-05-23):

> This will allow you to somewhat mitigate the downside of drawing a second copy of a Planeswalker by playing that copy to, in effect, refresh the loyalty of a Planeswalker or to get a second enters-the-battlefield trigger on a legendary permanent.

Here's the rule covering Legendary permanents:

> 704.5k If a player controls two or more legendary permanents with the same name, that player
> chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners’ graveyards. This is called the
> “legend rule.”

Note that in order for the Legendary state-based action to be triggered, the Legendary permanents are both already on the battlefield and therefore any triggered enters the battlefield abilities (ETB) are also triggered. As the Legend rule is a state-based action, the choice of which Legendary permanent will be kept will be made before the ETB triggered abilities are put on the stack and resolve.

Comment: Slight timing nitpick: the ability triggers before SBAs are checked, but is technically placed on the stack afterwards. I can't think of a scenario where the exact order matters though.

Comment: @MichaelSnook - you have to declare targets when an ability is put on the stack. That the "legendary rule" effect happens before triggered abilities are put on the stack is what allows Sharuum + Sculpting Steel to go infinite.

Comment: @Hao You'd think I would remember that since one of the people I play with has a Sharuum deck

Comment: So to be clear, one of the legendaries is discarded immediately when checking state-based actions after the abilities go on the stack but before they resolve?

Comment: @MichaelSnook Thanks for the catch! I've reworded the offending paragraph so that Sharuum isn't sad.

Comment: @Samthere As Michael pointed out, you actually discard one of the legendaries before any ETB triggered abilities are even put on the stack.