# Triggered ability of another card when two legendary creatures with the same name enter to the battlefield at the same time

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Temur Ascendancy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Temur%20Ascendancy) and a [Savage Knuckleblade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Savage%20Knuckleblade) in the battlefield then I use [See the Unwritten](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=See%20the%20Unwritten) and put 2 [Dragonlord Atarka](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dragonlord%20Atarka) into the battlefield. Do I draw one card or two cards?

I know that only one [Dragonlord Atarka](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dragonlord%20Atarka) would trigger the damage ability and I should sacrifice one. But what happens with [Temur Ascendancy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Temur%20Ascendancy)?

Comment: Im not asking for the trigger of a second legendary's ability... Moreover in my question they enter at the same time...

Comment: @RenatoSanhueza But that question does pretty much explain why you're wrong about only getting one damage trigger off Atarka. And... the reason that Temur Ascendancy triggers is the same reason that Atarka triggers: Atarka (both copies of her) entered the battlefield.

Comment: (Side note: the legend rule doesn't actually cause you to literally *sacrifice* anything. The extra copy/copies are just put into your graveyard. So if you have something that says "whenever you sacrifice a creature..." it won't trigger.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [See the Unwritten](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSee%20the%20Unwritten%5d), two creatures with a power greater than or equal to 4 have entered the battlefield. Each is sufficient to trigger the conditional statement of [Temur Ascendancy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTemur%20Ascendancy%5d)'s triggered ability, creating two effects that can be placed on the stack. You get the option, twice, to draw a card.

You're wrong about Dragonlord Atarka: in order for it to trigger the Legendary rule, the second creature must enter the battlefield. Since it has entered the battlefield, the triggered effect occurs to be put on the stack. [Reference:](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24326/can-i-get-an-enters-the-battlefield-effect-out-of-a-second-legendary-before-i-mu)

You've simultaneously created 4 effects, two draw effects and two damage effects. As the controller, you decided the order in which they enter the stack.